# Deployed Nodejs Express Application not getting request from the built React Client

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

I have a project which I have deployed successfully on Heroku.
My server is made with Node.js + Express and client is with ReactJS. I am rendering reactJS page with

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));
 app.get("*", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,  "../client/dist", "index.html"));
 });
}
```

This is my entire server index.js code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const cors =require('cors');
const request = require('request');
const words = require('./words');
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');
/*
const apiKey = process.env.google_place_api_key;
app.use(cors({
  origin:'http://localhost:8080',
  credentials:true
}));*/
const apiKey=process.env.apiKey;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,  "../client/dist", "index.html"));
  });
}
app.get('/city',(req,res)=>{
  console.log("allo allo");
  const cityname = req.query.name;
  let resArray=[];
  request({
    uri:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json',
    qs:{
      query:"point of interest in"+cityname,
      key:apiKey
    }
  },(err,request,body)=>{
    const object = JSON.parse(body);
    let photo;
    let placeObject={
      placeName:'',
      photo:''
    }
    for(let i=0;i<object.results.length;i++){
      if(object.results[i].photos!==undefined){
        placeObject['placeName']=words.returnWordsInEnglish(object.results[i].name);
        placeObject['photo'] =object.results[i].photos[0]['photo_reference'];
      }
      
  
      //getImageOfPlace(photo);
      resArray[i]=Object.assign({},placeObject);
    }
    res.send(resArray);
  });
 });

app.listen(process.env.PORT||port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app  listening on port ${process.env.PORT||port}!`)
});

async function getImageOfPlace(place){
  try{
    const response = await fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo? maxwidth=400&photo_reference='+place+'&key='+apiKey);
    //const json = await response.json();
    console.log(response);
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

And I am sending just fetch request to the Nodejs server

```
fetch("myherokusite.com/city?name="+searchValue,{
 method:'GET',
 credentials:'include',
 headers:{
  'Accept':'application/json',
  'Content-Type':'application/json'
 }
}).then((data:any)=>{
    console.log("data");
    console.log(data);
    return data.json();
}).then(data=>{
    console.log(data);
    setResult(Object.entries(data));
})
```

So, I am trying to send nodejs request with for example `/city?name="Madrid"`, and I thought node.js should print `allo allo` in my console but actually it is never happening.

[image]

With 200 status code, I see client can find server but console message allo allo is never printed out.. What should I fix in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes are matched in the order they are created. You create `app.get('*', ...)` as first route, so every GET request that doesn't match a static file is served by that handler.

Move route to be the last one. Ie as fallback when all other routes didn't match

Comment: Oh damn I never thought that is the reason. Thank you!